# CSS select element which not have TWO criteria

Tags: css, select

```
#cp_sidebar_contents .cp_sb_subform input:not([type=submit] && [type=button]){
   height:25px;
}
```

As you can see the code above, I want to select an element which DO NOT HAVE TWO criteria.

It is working if I only put one criteria in the not() function..

But how to not(two criteria) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain the `:not` selectors, like `#cp_sidebar_contents .cp_sb_subform input:not([type=submit]):not([type=button])`

Comment: how about if i want to select an element which HAVE TWO CRITERIA
...i tried this code, but NOT WORKING ------> 
#cp_sidebar_contents .cp_sb_subform input[type=submit][type=button]{
  height:200px;
 }

Comment: If you want to select `input[type=submit]`and `input[type=button]`, you'll have to separate them by comma, like `input[type=button], input[type=submit]`